# Is mum/mam/mom etc ever capitalised?

Tags: capitalization

When referring to a general mother, I'd always just use lowercase.

> Our mums went shopping together. Your mum bought a new suitcase.

However, when addressing my specific mum, I couldn't decide whether or not to capitalize the M.

> You'll have to adopt that dog **M**am; we want to see it.
>   When are you coming to England mam?

Comment: Your last two examples look like ***mam*** = contracted form of ***Madam*** (usually written as capitalised ***Ma'am*** because it's a form of address), which isn't the same usage as ***mam = mom = mum*** = diminutive of ***Mummy = Mother***.

Comment: Not sure if I've misread your comment now, however the mam in my example is my mother, not a stranger

Comment: oic. I didn't read very carefully. The final question just looked like something an "England-based" servant might say on the phone to the lady of the house on an extended stay Stateside. Anyway, I think bib has nailed the key factors (indifferently observed) governing capitalistion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Have you never been as far as the West Midlands? In 1962 I lived in digs with a family who had migrated from Nuneaton to Great Yarmouth. The kids all said 'mam'. And their friends at school looked askance when they said 'me mam packed me a snap box'. It is true that the Queen likes to be called Ma'am rhyming with 'ham' and definitely definitely NOT with 'farm'. But that has nothing to do with the West Midlands. I'm trying to remember if George Elliot uses 'mam'.

Comment: @ws2 _Billy_ Elliot does =p

Comment: @JamesWebster Do Geordies say 'mam'? That's interesting if they do, because Yorkshire and Lancashire don't. What's =p?

Comment: Yeah a good number of us do. Certainly as far south as Middlesbrough. And at least a few of my friends from Cumbria do.

Comment: I don't know if it stretches up into Scotland

Comment: @JamesWebster It's interesting how it crossed Yorks and Lancs and got into the Midlands. But then I never cease to be surprised at the West Midlands' accent. It is like nothing else on earth!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I must apologise if I misunderstood you. Having re-read your post it is clear you did know about mam=mum.

Comment: @WS2, I read it wrongly at first too.

Comment: @WS2: *mamma* occurs 35 times in [*Middlemarch*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/145/145-h/145-h.htm), but there's not a single *mam, mom,* or *mum* there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't they say *mammy* in the southern USA? Just thinking of Al Jolson. Where did they get it from? Do the Irish say 'mammy'?

Comment: @WS2: My Lancastrian father and Liverpudlian brother-in-law always say *mammy*, never *mummy* (only Americans say *mommy*). And there's a whole 200+ page publication [The Book of Irish Mammies](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dZYvy13-fYQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22irish+mammy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BfbdVPmmJtL3apSjgMgP&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22irish%20mammy%22&f=false), so obviously it's common as muck there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But it is clean muck that they have in Ireland. Noticed that when I was there last summer.

Comment: @WS2, FumbleFingers This is an interesting set of [maps](http://imgur.com/a/ca07b)

Comment: @JamesWebster Interesting. But they seem to raise more questions than they supply answers. but well done for digging them out.

Comment: I was thinking of making the map myself, but no point reinventing the wheel. =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the book 'Painless Grammar' by Rebecca, PhD

Capitalize 'mom' and 'dad' when you are calling your parent's name **but** not when you refer to 'my mom' and 'my dad'.

**CAPS**

> Hi Mom! Welcome home, Dad

**NO CAPS**

> My father and my mother are busy. Could your mom or dad drive us to the movie?

Answer (score 6):

Mother and its alternatives are capitalized when they are used as a form of direct address or a title (effectively in lieu of the person's name).

> Mom, can I take the car?
>
> 'Night, Mother.
>
> Cuppa tea, Mam?

but

> I asked my mother if I could take the car. She said "no".
>
> Your mum is a looker!

Reference to one's mother without a determiner (such as *my*) more often is treated like a title and gets capitalized

> I asked Mother if I could take the car.

While some might use the lower case for this last example, this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20asked%20mother%2C%20I%20asked%20Mother&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20mother%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20Mother%3B%2Cc0) shows such usage as much less common (thanks to FumbleFingers for this point).

Comment: I settled on capitalising with the same rationale. I just wasn't certain. :)

Comment: I disagree. In the vast majority of cases, [I asked mother if](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+asked+Mother+if%2CI+asked+mother+if&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20Mother%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20mother%20if%3B%2Cc0) uses the capitalised form, as I would expect. You don't normally capitalise in constructions like ***your** mother/mum*, but when it refers to a *specific* individual with no such "determiner", it's capitalised the same as when it's used in direct address.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+asked+mother%2C+I+asked+Mother&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20mother%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20Mother%3B%2Cc0) your position. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @bib: No! [**This** ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+asked+Mother+if%2CI+asked+mother+if&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20Mother%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20mother%20if%3B%2Cc0) my position. [**That** ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+asked+mother%2C+I+asked+Mother&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20mother%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20asked%20Mother%3B%2Cc0) yours (I just happened to include your original ***if***! :) But downvote reversed

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just looking for the broader set of examples (and I clumsily omitted *supports* in my comment).